# regex opltional matching groups

Tags: c#, regex

Hi im trying to create a regex for the following expression

I need matching groups on all the integers

- Valid

  - integer-integer
  - integer-integer/integer
- Invalid

  - integer-integer/

So the first part would be like

^(\d+)-(\d+)

which matches 
1-50

With these matching groups

- 1st group: 1
- 2nd group: 50

what do i need to add to the second part to make

/integer

optional but / should not be in the 3rd matching group and an integer is supplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-capturing optional group, and inside it the integer group.

This should work for you:

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the slash inside a non-capturing group, and the number after it in a capture group.

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?
```